# Nested regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have a string with alphanumeric values. The numeric values are variables. The alphabetic values are always `'abc'` and `'ghi'`, but I don't know their order.
The numeric values come always after the alphabetic values.

Valid examples of this kind of string are:

```
a = 'abc10ghi1450'
b = 'abc11ghi9285'
c = 'ghi1abc9'
...
```

Now I want to store the numbers after `'abc'` and `'ghi'` into appropriate variables and what I'm doing is:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'abc10ghi44'
>>> abc = re.search('abc\d+', string).group(0)
>>> abc = re.search('\d+', abc).group(0)
>>> ghi = re.search('ghi\d+', string).group(0)
>>> ghi = re.search('\d+', ghi).group(0)
>>> print abc, ghi
10, 44
```

For each variable I'm using 2 regexes and I don't like it; is there a smarter way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, make a capturing group around the digits and use that:

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'abc10ghi44'
>>> re.search('abc(\d+)', string).group(1)
'10'
```

Note parentheses around `\d+` and `1` in the `group` call.

---

Alternatively, use a *positive lookbehind*:

```
>>> re.search('(?<=abc)\d+', string).group(0)
'10'
```